# JQGrid Master Detail XML

Tags: jqgrid

I have setup a master/detail which shows the correct entries for each record.
However when a new record in the detail grid is created a field in the Add form of the detail grid should be filled out with a value from the master grid.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You should add code like this:

```
onclickSubmit: function(re, data){
var master_id = mastertGrid.getGridParam('selrow');
return {'master_id' : master_id };
}
```

in the "add options" of the slave grid.
[Have a look at this post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=468).